# Format JavaScript date to "Month day, Year" format

Tags: javascript, html

I want to get following date format (by JavaScript only) - **March 3, 2020**

```js
var date = new Date();
console.log(date);
```

Currently I am getting in "**2020-05-11T10:08:43.322Z**" format. Kindly, help!

Comment: You've only created a date, but haven't tried to format it. Why don't you try it first and look in to the [docs at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) on what you can use to do it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to format a JavaScript date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552461/how-to-format-a-javascript-date)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can check [Date.prototype.toLocaleString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString) for more information

```js
var date = new Date();
console.log(date.toLocaleString('en-US', {month: 'long', day: 'numeric', year: 'numeric'}));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/)

```js
let date = moment().format('MMMM DD, YYYY');
console.log(date)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.19.1/moment.min.js" integrity="sha256-zG8v+NWiZxmjNi+CvUYnZwKtHzFtdO8cAKUIdB8+U9I=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```